# Are there margins such that, while the "correlation" parameters of a Gaussian copula are positive, the correlations between the margins are negative?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, correlation, multivariate-analysis, copula, marginal-distribution

Let there be a multivariate distribution $F$ with margins $F_1,\dots,F_n$ and a Gaussian copula with "correlation" matrix $\Sigma$. Let the off-diagonal elements of $\sigma$ be positive.

Let $X=\left(X_1,\dots,X_n\right)\sim F$ be a multivariate random variable. Are there any margins $F_1,\dots,F_n$ such that, despite the off-diagonal elements of $\Sigma$ being positive, $\text{cor}\left(X_i, X_j\right)<0$ for some $i$ and $j$ (negative Pearson correlation between two of the margins)?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, multivariate copula models impose the same dependency structures among all variables. So, no, you cannot.

Comment: @Dave Is there a case where this won't just come down to the question of whether there's a pair of monotonic increasing transformations of the margins of a bivariate normal that has negative correlation? I'm not sure I see how the other variables come into it.

Comment: @Glen_b I think a bivariate distribution should be sufficient but don’t want to lock potential responders into that. If you know of such a transformation, I think that would answer my question in the affirmative, though the lack of such a transformation should mean the answer must be in the negative.

Comment: Shouldn't mean the answer must be in the negative...